# How to do functional de-structuring with an interface inside a class in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a Class with a method that I'd like to use in a de-structured way, mostly due to several optional arguments. I would also like to keep the strict typing so I created an Interface to describe the arguments.

To be clear, this works just fine today, albeit a bit cumbersome, especially if most functions take de-structured arguments.

***My question is**: Is it possible to define an interface inside the class?*

The reason is purely for code readability/maintenance: for larger classes, I have to scroll to outside the class to make changes to a "function" interface, where it would be much clearer to have the interface next to the function

**Example of what works:**

```js
interface LoadUsersInterface {
  status: 'active' | 'inactive',
  options?: QueryOptions
}

class UserService {
  loadUsers({ status, options }: LoadUsersInterface) {
    ...
  }  
}
```

**Example of what I would like:**

```js
class UserService {
 
  interface LoadUsersInterface {
    status: 'active' | 'inactive',
    options?: QueryOptions
  }

 loadUsers({ status, options }: LoadUsersInterface) {
    ...
  }  
}
```

***Note:** This is being done within an Angular 11 app, in case there's any magic there that I don't know about, although I think this is more of a JS / TypeScript question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to declare types or interfaces directly inside of a `class` body.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#7061](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061) for the relevant feature request, and specifically there is [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061#issuecomment-394802612) which mentions the particular use case of declaring types so they are next to the methods that use them.  It is a relatively old issue, and while it is technically open, it is labeled  "Revisit".  While it's possible something will eventually happen to support this, I wouldn't count on it.  You may wish to go there and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's there, but I doubt it will make much of a difference either way.

For now there are only workarounds.  If you need a named type, you should probably just declare it outside the class the way you are currently doing and deal with the inconvenience of scrolling.

If you don't need a name because you only use it once, you can use an anonymous type directly where you would normally refer to the name:

```
class UserService {    
    loadUsers({ status, options }: {
        status: 'active' | 'inactive',
        options?: QueryOptions
    }) {
        // impl
    }
}
```

But this might not be as clean as you'd like.  Oh well!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE8DyAHMYAexAGdkBvAWAChaBfW2hAGzlPIFVToBlaAG7AklJjWQTkLInAAm3aKQAUFZKTBww6UgBpkRAsTLJ6ALlHjJV9Zu3mA5IkICI95AB9k90E+Av7OrRWVgaEJKQA-OYY2PhhZEGS9ACUFsGSAPQZyMAAtngsiRKMNCW0QA)

Comment: I thought so after looking around for a few hours... Hearing it from someone else is all I needed :-) I think we're just going to go with the way I described. I'd like to keep the ability to import the interface on the calling side as well so that everything is rock solid.

Answer (score 1):

you can define the interface in the method signature. It will save having an additional file but may be hard to read if the list of parameters grow.

```js
class UserService { 
 loadUsers(payload: {status: 'active' | 'inactive', options?: QueryOptions}) {
    console.log(payload.status);
  }  
}
```

[checkout the typescript play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiA8mYBLA9gOwM5QC8UA3gFBSVQD01UOWwUeci0A7gBYCGTwnGAoLIBfANxkyAYwA23PAQCqeJAGUkANwxToJKBRlZuAE2VI8ACjDcQhkwC5KJPMF5w8jgOTcpmDRE8oAB8oTwwcHz8AgBooLHRsfAB%20R3gkVATcPBEASlIKKiksrBkIADpDAHMrGztjMpc3PByJShFKUUki-CZ3InoIdigzRHVELR0LFrJ3CqNTFURLZ1dgd3sAIkiMfw3coA)